# When I use a .xib file to layout my viewController IBOutlets aren't being released when the view controller is released

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I use a .xib to layout my viewController and have 10 IBOutlet objects that IB uses, none of them have @properties assigned to them (no @property(retain) IBOutlet...).  When I release the viewController none of those objects are being released, I have to manually release them in the dealloc of the viewController.

This doesn't seem like normal behavior, I thought that those objects would be released by the system since IB is whats assigning them, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) tells you exactly how to [properly release IBOutlets](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004998-SW2).

In short, you are supposed to release them in dealloc, but you also want to release them in viewDidUnload.

Comment: Ah, is this new behavior in 4.x now that we have a viewDidUnload and it used to just handle it for you in 3.x?

Comment: They are assigned to your ivars, so you own them, so you have to release them. *This has always been the case.* In the past, Leaks didn't detect certain kinds of garbage (it would never detect a leaked UIImageView); perhaps they fixed this. I also highly recommend using properties and using `self.foo = nil` instead; I cringe when I see code which releases ivars without setting them to nil.

Comment: Thanks, and agreed re: setting things to nil.